# How to update a bars chart series values C# when I click a button?

Tags: c#, charts

I have a winform with 3 textboxes as options and 3 buttons as the option selection. When I fill them I pass the text to chart series. After that I click on a button, and I add a value to each "option" as a percentage.

Option 1: II
Option 2: IIIII
Option 3: I

But every time I click on a button I got this:

[image]

I want to consider in the same bar (different series). This is the code:

```
    private void btnOpt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        opt1++;
        avg1 = (opt1 * 100) / total;
        crtStats.Series["Option 1"].Points.AddXY("Options", avg1);            
    }
```

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `AddXY("Options", avg1)` Adding X-Values as strings is always a bad idea which will result in all sorts of problems. Strings are converted to double resulting in x-values of `0` for all points. Most likely your issue.. - What outputs do you want when clicking a few times?

Comment: The output I want is just to have one bar for each serie not to be creating a bar by every click. For example now if I click 5 times on Option 1 get 5 blue bars. I want just to have one bar considering the 5 clicks.

Comment: If you don't want to add new DataPoints don't do it! You can change the YValue[0] of a DataPoint if you know its Series and index in the Points collection, if that is what you want. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370297/c-sharp-add-to-y-value-on-chart/41370503#41370503)