# If exception does not occur - does it affect performance?

Tags: java, exception, bytecode

I have written a method, and added an exception handling block.

I have looked at the bytecode and I have seen it added the following line at the top of the method.

```
TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 java/lang/Exception
```

and not much of bytecode, actually in the `try` block there isn't any bytecode.

So, out of curiosity, If exceptions do not occur - do they affect performance?

btw - not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308432/do-try-catch-blocks-hurt-performance-when-exceptions-are-not-thrown), since the answers are not related (dotnet, irrelevant tests).