# Does more specific exception handling improve performance?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-micro-framework

If I can catch a more specific exception do I prevent the clr from doing extra work and benefit performance wise ?  So if I know I might get a socket exception but do not care about handling it differently than some other exception is it better to still have the more specific catch ?  I am working on the MicroFramework so small improvements in performance and resources are worth asking about.

```
 catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException netEx)
            {

            }

 catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Performance is directly related to algorithm complexity and related to how much code must be executed. Having two "catch" statements, simple spoken it is like having two IFs instead of a single IF statement. For this case, more MSIL must be generated to handle two possible situations so there will be more code JIT-ed. But I would NOT consider giving up catching specific exceptions!!! It is very important to catch specific exceptions because you can react more acuratelly and can recover easier.

Comment: Wrong question on so many levels.

Comment: How is it the wrong question ?  I am not asking for design help.  I'm not asking for best practices.  I am curious if there is a performance difference between a more granular exception catch vs a more general exception catch.

Comment: I think it’s worth mentioning there is no JIT for the .NET Micro Framework. All MSIL is interpreted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not think about this in terms of performance.

From a code correctness perspective: You should almost always `catch` the most specific exception you can.

When you catch `Exception` your exception handler will swallow *any* exception even if you are not prepared to handle it. Imagine an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown. The catch block would swallow it and cause confusion.

If all you are prepared to handle is a `SocketException` then just catch that. If it is less performant so be it. Code correctness is not something to sacrifice for such a miniscule performance gain*

* or no performance gain at all - I am *almost* certain there is *zero* execution time performance implication at all. I did a benchmark on my computer and the performance is more or less equal. It was not a comprehensive test but it was enough to confirm my instinct. You can run your own benchmark using a technique similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308432/do-try-catch-blocks-hurt-performance-when-exceptions-are-not-thrown)