# Dictionary ArgumentException log duplicate key: which is more performant?

Tags: c#, dictionary, try-catch, big-o

Here I add something to a `Dictionary`:

```
dictionary.Add(dictionaryKey, value);
```

if `dictionaryKey` already exists, an `ArgumentException` will be thrown. Its message is fairly generic:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

If my call to `dictionary.Add` is inside of a loop or a helper function, it can be hard to tell immediately what key has already been added that is throwing this exception. I would like to know this as easily and as soon as possible.

There are a few options.

1)

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(dictionaryKey))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"An item with the same key ({dictionaryKey}) has already been added.");
}

dictionary.Add(dictionaryKey, value);
```

2. 

```
try
{
    dictionary.Add(dictionaryKey, value);
}
catch (ArgumentException argumentException)
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"An item with the same key ({dictionaryKey}) has already been added.");
}
```

3. Some other way

I know setting up a try/catch block takes a performance hit, but it seems running `dictionary.ContainsKey(dictionaryKey)` would mean an additional lookup each time too. Which of these options is most performant?

Comment: I would go with first approach as dictionary contains has only O(1) complexity. Exception handling should not be used in such case.

Comment: Try/catch blocks don't provoke any performance hit at all, it's the throwing of an exception that does

Comment: Shouldn't there already be an indication in the error message of what was being inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core introduced the [`TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd) method, that allows to do it with a single lookup:

```
if (!dictionary.TryAdd(key))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"An item with the same key ({key}) has already been added.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the context of this code falls into, but in terms of performance, it will depend if you are expecting duplicate `dictionaryKey`s.

If there are going to duplicates, I would go with the first method, as `ContainsKey` is an O(1) operation, while `try`/`catch` incurs a [small performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308480/4607317) if used to handle control flow. Presumably, this penalty will be greater than O(1).

However if you can guarantee no duplicate `dictionaryKey`s, the second method would be faster. The `try`/`catch` performance penalty only occurs if an exception is thrown (a duplicate key is found). The first method will be performing an unnecessary call to `ContainsKey`. Of course, this means you don't need to wrap the code in a `try`/`catch` in the first place, defeating the purpose of your question.

I would go with the first method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party here, sorry.

Perhaps you could add a key-value pair into the `ArgumentException.Data` property to indicate the offending key?

e.g.

```
string key = foo;

try
{
  someDictionary.Add(key, "Hello");
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
  e.Data.Add("DuplicateKey", key);
  throw;
}
```

You could further qualify the exception by doing a message comparison (e.g. `An item with the same key has already been added`) in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I would say number one is better. Because when you use the second method it will trigger an runtime error and that means it will create an additional Exception object in the memory which referenced by the variable "argumentException" in the catch phrase.