# how to include the actual form classname in logging from FirstChanceException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, stack-trace

My situation is as follows:

- I have a form `FormBase`
- From this `FormBaseList` and `FormBaseDetail` are inherited

now on my mainform I want to log some exceptions from then FirstChanceException event.  I log the `Exception.Message` and the full `stacktrace`

But in the `stacktrace` I have a problem.
For example I create a form `FormCustomerDetail` and its derived from `FormBaseDetail`.
And an exception occurs in a protected or private method defined in `FormBaseDetail` then the stacktrace will show `FormBaseDetail` in stead of `FormCustomerDetail`
This is a problem for me, because now I cant know what actual form the exception happend on. There are about 50 forms derived from `FormBaseDetail`

So the question is, is there a way in the `FirstChanceException` event to retrieve the classname  of the actual form ? Or the Name ?

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;

private void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    StackTrace stackTraceObject = new StackTrace();
    string stackTrace = stackTraceObject.ToString();

    // I need to retrieve the actual form name or classname here...
    LogError(
      //ActualFormName + Environment.NewLine +  
      e.Exception.GetType().FullName + Environment.NewLine +  
      e.Exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + 
      stackTrace);
}
```

Example of a logentry:

```
System.FormatException
Cannot convert xx to type boolean...
...
at Test_app.FormBaseDetail.OpenTables()  
at Test_app.FormBaseDetail.PrepareFormLoad()
...
```

What I would like to get

```
Exeption occured in FormCustomerDetail
System.FormatException
Cannot convert xx to type boolean...
...
at Test_app.FormBaseDetail.OpenTables()  
at Test_app.FormBaseDetail.PrepareFormLoad()
...
```

Comment: You're looking for a way to resolve the instances of local variables on stack when an exception occurs. Unfortunately the `StackTrace` class does not appear to support this. The debugger does, but that's probably not helpful here. -- Incidentally, it's first _chance_, not first change.

Answer (score 1):

Naive way would be to actually log it inside the base form - i.e. have something like:

```
class FormBaseDetail 
{
   private void Guard(Action a)
   {
       try { a.Invoke(); }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          throw new Exception("Exception on '" + this.GetType() + "'", e);
       }
   }

   // pretty much everywhere in base class
   public void PrepareFormLoad() 
   {
      Guard(() => { ... });
   }
}
```

Additionally I can imagine hooking on `FormLoad` and putting the active type of Form into some static variable for example.

Comment: yes but that will only work if i put that in every mehod of every form, right ?

Comment: @GuidoG - just the base form (FormBaseDetail - if exception happens in child form method (say FormCustomerDetail) you should be able to infer the type from the stack trace. But yeah - you'd have to put it into all FormBaseDetail methods.

Comment: ok, but will the invoke have any effect on performance or message queu ?

Comment: There is very, very, small performance penalty for every try block; but on UI operation I wouldn't mind it. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308432/do-try-catch-blocks-hurt-performance-when-exceptions-are-not-thrown

Comment: Well i suppose I can give this a try