# Will try catch - Cause high CPU usage?

Tags: c#, performance, model-view-controller

I am summarizing the Code. Following Code iterates almost 4000 times in a `foreach` loop. 
On my local IIS it is working but on Production Cloud Server the complete application crashes.

```
try
{
    cell.Value = decimal.Parse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
}
catch
{
    cell.Value = dr[dc.ColumnName];
}
```

My query is :- Will Using Catch block as above cause high CPU usage?

As an addition information :-
`Catch` is hitting 4000 times

Comment: And that's why there is [decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse). You may have to do null checking separately or else .ToString() might crash it.

Comment: There is no performance overhead adding a try catch in code. There is when exceptions are caught. They should be used to catch exceptional situations and not as a flow control. Doing so will make you fail lots of code reviews on your commits, will incur performance penalties. and also draw ire from future developers

Comment: If you assign the object to an object variable, why you need to parse it at all? You are unboxing an object, parsing that to decimal and then convert the result to a string, just to finally assign this string to an object variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. Throwing and catching exceptions isn't free, but it's not super-expensive either. However, if you call this code in a loop, like millions of times each second, and most of the time it throws an exception, then it will spend more CPU time on this. But this is rather besides the point as there are already good examples on how to avoid exceptions altogether here, at least for the most part, by using `decimal.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Also, why do you need `.ToString()`? Which type is the underlying value to begin with?

Comment: *Throwing* is expensive, not catching. Just use `TryParse`

Comment: @TheGeneral it's the opposite. There's no overhead in *catching* an exception. The performance hit comes when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, i saw that, and i fully agree, however my irreverence and point remains the same :)

Comment: Apart from this you shouldn´t handle exceptions which you can **avoid** in the first place. Exceptions are for something - well - exceptional. Anyway I doubt the overhead of an exception outperforms the time used for the actual db-query. Seems like your actual bottleneck is hitting the Database that often.

Comment: If you want to know where CPU time is being spent, a profiler is a far better investment of your (and everyone else's) time than trying to *guess* at the bottlenecks and their causes.

Comment: @Anup why the call to `ToString()`? If the value is a string, use `(string)`. If not, there's no reason to format a *number* as a string just to parse it back. That pointless format-and-parse-back hurts performance a *lot* more than exceptions

Comment: @Anup finally, all ASP.NET stacks support data binding. *Instead* of retrieving values one by one bind your grid to the data table. If `cell.Value` refers to an Excel cell, use eg `Epplus` and `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable()` to load the table all at once

Comment: @Anup `On my local IIS it is working but on Production Cloud Server the complete application crashes.` that means you have other bugs. 4K rows is such a small amount of data that a single core's cache could hold the values.

Comment: Please understand that i have just summarized the Code, it is not a complete Code. There is a complex code logic.

Comment: Chekc this SO question [https://stackoverflow.com/q/1308432/488699], it looks like the jit optimizations are affected by try catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having try-catch *present in your code* has a minimal, yet IMO neglectable performance cost: in the range of **< 0.001 µs** per 'try-that-didnt-catch' (using a .NET 4.6.1 Release build on my Core i7 x64 machine).

But *if it has to catch*, then it does cost quite a bit more: in the range of **12.5 µs** per 'try-that-had-to-catch' (using a .NET 4.6.1 Release build on my Core i7 machine). Still you may not notice until you get to the level of 10s of thousands of caught exceptions.

All in all it is much better to avoid throwing-and-catching if you can, and you can do so here by using [decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse).

You now have to do null checking separately or else the `.ToString()` might still crash it.

Rewritten code:

```
var v = dr[dc.ColumnName];
var s = v?.ToString(); // or you might use: var s = v as string;
if (s != null && decimal.TryParse(s, out decimal d))
    cell.Value = d;
else
    cell.Value = v;
```

Comment: Why keep `ToString()` ? If the value is a string, `(string)` should be enough. If not, what type is it? Perhaps it's already a decimal?

Comment: Assuming `dr` is a `DataRow`, then `dr[dc.ColumnName]` produces an **object** which `decimal.TryParse` does not accept. And if that object is in fact a string, then `.ToString()` will simply do `(string)`. But still this is something that OP might be able to improve on.

Comment: A type check could avoid the expensive format/parse cycle and the temporary object whether the boxed value is a string or not. The actual options for this value are a string, numeric type (which can be cast to decimal) or an invalid value

Comment: It appears that your answer is not acurate, check out this question [https://stackoverflow.com/q/1308432/488699]

Comment: I augmented my answer to include some timings.

Comment: Removing the `try catch` block & using `TryParse` solved my performance issue.